# Unittesting in .NET 6 with XUnit

Tags: c#, .net, xunit

I'm trying to learn and write best practice unittests and practice test driven design. Can you give me some tips and review my code?

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Moq;
using Xunit;

namespace Blockchain.Unittests
{
    public class AccountShould
    {
        private static string _webUrl = "https://test.test/test";

        [Fact]
        public async Task ReturnAccountBalance4EthWhenGivenAddress()
        {
            // Arrange
            var address = AccountData.Address;
            var web3RepositoryMock = new Mock<IWeb3Repository>();

            web3RepositoryMock
                .Setup(web3RepositoryMock => web3RepositoryMock.GetAccountBalanceInEth(It.IsAny<string>()))
                .ReturnsAsync(4);

            var account = new Account(web3RepositoryMock.Object);
            
            // Act
            var balance = await account.GetBalanceInEth(address);

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(4, balance);
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/mnirm/learning-blockchain/blob/feature/test-get-account-balance/Blockchain.Unittests/AccountShould.cs

Comment: In your test you are testing moq :)

Comment: Normally when we write unit tests then we make assertions against `ClassA`'s functionality, which relies on `ClassB`. We are mocking `ClassB` in order to focus only on `ClassA`'s code by making `ClassB`'s response deterministic and predictable.

Comment: In your case `accountStub` is the mocked `ClassB`. But you don't have `ClassA` in your test.

Comment: @PeterCsala so I should moq the Web3 class?

Comment: @PeterCsala what do you recommend me, how should I write this test then? I'm trying to learn and write good unit tests

Comment: Yes, `Web3` is the dependency (`ClassB` in my analogy) of `Account` (`ClassA` in my analogy). So if you want to test `GetAccountBalanceInEth` then you need to mock `SendRequestAsync` and `FromWei`. Unfortunately your `Account` relies on implementation rather than abstraction. (If `Web3` implements an interface which exposes `SendRequestAsync` then you should rely on that). Also your code relies on a static method (`FromWei`), which is really hard to mock.

Comment: @PeterCsala I refactored my code and made an repository for the web3 object and I mocked the repository then.

Comment: Since no review has been posted yet, you can update your questions code part to show us recent changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131376/discussion-between-mounir-mehjoub-and-peter-csala).

Comment: @PeterCsala don, updated my review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GetBalanceInEth` is a wrapper around the `GetAccountBalanceInEth` call. That's why you can't test too much things.

But this here are my advices:

- Rename your test to follow the `Given-When-Then` pattern
- Preserve `4` in a `const` so you can express the intent that `Account` does not modify that value

```
public async Task GivenAValidAddressAndAFlawlessRepository_WhenICallGetBalanceInEth_ThenItReturnsTheOutputWithoutModification()
{
    // Arrange
    const decimal expectedBalance = 4;
    var address = AccountData.Address;
    var web3RepositoryMock = new Mock<IWeb3Repository>();

    web3RepositoryMock
        .Setup(web3RepositoryMock => web3RepositoryMock.GetAccountBalanceInEth(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(expectedBalance);

    var account = new Account(web3RepositoryMock.Object);
    
    // Act
    var balance = await account.GetBalanceInEth(address);

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(expectedBalance, balance);
}
```

- Write a test to make sure that the your `GetAccountBalanceInEth` does not swallow exception

```
public async Task GivenAnInvalidAddressAndAFlaultyRepository_WhenICallGetBalanceInEth_ThenItThrowsUriFormatException()
{
    // Arrange
    string errorMessage = "The provided url is malformed";
    UriFormatException toBeThrownException = new UriFormatException(errorMessage);
    var address = AccountData.Address;
    var web3RepositoryMock = new Mock<IWeb3Repository>();

    web3RepositoryMock
        .Setup(web3RepositoryMock => web3RepositoryMock.GetAccountBalanceInEth(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .ThrowsAsync(toBeThrownException);

    var account = new Account(web3RepositoryMock.Object);
    
    // Act
    Func<Task> act = () => account.GetBalanceInEth(address);

    // Assert
    UriFormatException ex = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<UriFormatException>(act);
    Assert.Contains(errorMessage, ex.Message);
}
```